# Plausible explanation why my grandpa isn't famous

Tags: internal-consistency

My grandpa is smart. Like, really smart. He's (self described) *the smartest man in the universe*. But seriously, he creates Turing-test level AI robots just to pass him the butter. He makes stuff that can easily destroy the planet as a side effect. He travels across space and different realities on a daily basis. He uses his portal gun to come grab me at my school so I'll come with him to adventures. He goes shopping either with his space ship or he sends a robot. You get the idea.

What strikes me as weird is that there are no TV vans in the streets. He barely has face recognition in my school even though he's been there several times with different sci-fi gadgets. He can walk around in the streets, or fly above them with the only space ship on the planet, and no one will be like "hey, there's this really famous genius". The most anyone has ever said about him was "hi isn't your grandpa, like, a scientist?"

It's not like he's shy. We're talking about someone who's turned himself to a teenager once. Who created super intelligent dogs the eventually started a war with humans. He brought all kinds of aliens and AI that the world has never seen before. Not even a morning show special.

**How can the smartest man in the universe keep his anonymity?**

Looking for a plausible explanation that requires the least amount of ongoing effort from my grandpa. (Can assume a one-time significant effort)

Comment: There are many, many very accomplished people that are virtually unknown.

Comment: Because he's a hopeless drunk and no one believes the things he claims work as he claims they will.

Comment: Isn't this an episode of Rick and Morty?

Comment: @Raditz_35 they didn't have space ships though

Comment: Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problem with questions like this is they are not objective and you've provided no criteria for judging a best answer. Please remember that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).

Comment: They did other stuff, more useful stuff mostly. There are some pretty famous astronauts out there right now, but really, how many can you name from the top of your head? How many TV vans follow them around?

Comment: @Raditz_35 is basically right.  Intelligence breeds little fame.  How many scientists can the average person name?  Einstein, Hawking, maybe Oppenheimer (who wouldn't be famous were it not for writing that Hindu quote in his journal). I'm an EE, so I remember Berkley and Schottky, and of course my peers, Gates, Jobs, and who was the other guy with Jobs?  (You see my point.)  Intelligence must work like a dog for fame outside its professional peer groups. Remember that this is different from being good at what you do, which is why we remember athletes, soldiers, etc. That and they're boistrous.

Comment: Because he didn't host a reality show

Comment: How many Field Medalists do you recognize by name? Very smart people often work on subjects that only other very smart people are even aware exist.

Comment: One more thing, since you are obviously talking about Rick from The Rick and Morty, if I were you, I wouldn't ask how the "smartest" man is unknown but rather about how someone exhibiting all of his personaily traits stays unknown. Really boring people don't get to be famous and many experts are really boring. Really exciting people are another story though

Comment: @Raditz_35 this is exactly what I'm asking

Answer (score 2):

He's not the smartest man alive. I am. I'm not famous because I'm lazy. Not so lazy I never do anything.. just so lazy I never do anything I don't want to do. I'm smart enough to have achieved that. And so it is with your Grandad. Smart people have principles. Like never dealing with idiots.

Answer (score 1):

> How can the smartest man in the universe keep his anonymity?

Simple, because he doesn't wish to be known. If he is that smart he could easily be able to cover his tracks. In a world run by machines and social media, he could write programs to penetrate systems and erase information about him.

Kind of hard for modern media to catch wind of or believe in someone teleporting places when all videos and tweets and pictures disappear as soon as they appear on the net.

Any people trying to pass verbal stories would be considered nut jobs with today's level of scrutiny.